# Need help on value comparison using XSLT - Compare 2 parent nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have a XML which have two parent nodes (Base, Sub). I need to write a XSLT to get the values for below condition.

Condition: Need to get different elements in both parents.

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
  <Base>
    <Student_ID>1234</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>1267</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>1890</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>5678</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>6743</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>8743</Student_ID>
  </Base>
  <Sub>
    <Student_ID>5678</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>6743</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>3226</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>8123</Student_ID>
  </Sub>
</Data>
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <Student_ID>1234</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>1267</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>1890</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>8743</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>3226</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>8123</Student_ID>
</Data>
```

Comment: What did you try your self?

Comment: I tried to use key. But it gives the matching values. @SiebeJongebloed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 3 you could also consider `xsl:merge`, that would allow you to handle duplicates in each branch; drawback is that merging requires sorting input sequences on merge key(s) so the result of

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:merge>
        <xsl:merge-source name="base" select="Base/Student_ID" sort-before-merge="yes">
          <xsl:merge-key select="."/>
        </xsl:merge-source>
        <xsl:merge-source name="sub" select="Sub/Student_ID" sort-before-merge="yes">
          <xsl:merge-key select="."/>
        </xsl:merge-source>
        <xsl:merge-action>
          <xsl:if test="count(current-merge-group('base')) = 0 and count(current-merge-group('sub')) = 1 or count(current-merge-group('base')) = 1 and count(current-merge-group('sub')) = 0">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-merge-group()"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:merge-action>
      </xsl:merge>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

has the right elements but in sorted order:

```
<Data>
   <Student_ID>1234</Student_ID>
   <Student_ID>1267</Student_ID>
   <Student_ID>1890</Student_ID>
   <Student_ID>3226</Student_ID>
   <Student_ID>8123</Student_ID>
   <Student_ID>8743</Student_ID>
</Data>
```

Of course we could re-sort into original input order using

```
 <xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:variable name="unique-ids" as="element(Student_ID)*">
      <xsl:merge>
        <xsl:merge-source name="base" select="Base/Student_ID" sort-before-merge="yes">
          <xsl:merge-key select="."/>
        </xsl:merge-source>
        <xsl:merge-source name="sub" select="Sub/Student_ID" sort-before-merge="yes">
          <xsl:merge-key select="."/>
        </xsl:merge-source>
        <xsl:merge-action>
          <xsl:if test="count(current-merge-group('base')) = 0 and count(current-merge-group('sub')) = 1 or count(current-merge-group('base')) = 1 and count(current-merge-group('sub')) = 0">
            <xsl:sequence select="current-merge-group()"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:merge-action>
      </xsl:merge>
     </xsl:variable>
     <xsl:copy-of select="$unique-ids/."/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Nice solution. Could the if statement not be made somewhat simpler, like this?
`<xsl:if test="count(current-merge-group('base')) + count(current-merge-group('sub')) = 1 ">`

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed, that is a good simplification, yes.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you for the support and it's working perfectly. I'm new to XSLT and could you please explain me how this code works and how the same values in Base and Sub eliminates when merging.

Comment: Start by reading https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#merging. As for the merging, the `current-merge-group()` contains any merged items from all merge sources (e.g. `base` and `sub`) but inside of the `xsl:merge-action` we can check which merge group contains how many items and that way it is possible to only output a merged group if either the `base` or the `sub` group had a single item.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="student" match="Student_ID" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Base/Student_ID[not(key('student', ., ../../Sub))]"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Sub/Student_ID[not(key('student', ., ../../Base))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could look at it:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*/Student_ID" group-by=".">
            <xsl:if test="count(current-group())=1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes there are no duplicates within each branch.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(*/Student_ID)">
  <Student_ID>{.}</Student_ID>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: No, that's what I first though too but `<Student_ID>5678</Student_ID>` is not in the wanted result.